# How to get the component that rendered a dom element with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

How to get the component that rendered a dom element with Vue.js ?

For example, suppose you want to retrieve which component "owns" a dom element that the user has selected, how would you do ? (it seems to be implemented in the dev tools, but I can't find a way neither in the documentation, neither on SO)

(I mean, given the DOM element, I know how to retrieve what element is selected)

**DISCLAIMER : This may not be the right solution for common use cases. Always prefer handling event & co. in the root component using direct sub-component reference if you can**

Comment: Isnt this a concern of abstraction? the more you abstract details down into further components the simpler it should be to understand what 'owns' what, if you make an overly complicated component it should normally be broken down into smaller pieces especially when it comes to ownership of a certain part of your interface.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going to downvote this post as it actually doesn't make much sense, your asking for a way to find out what component rendered the html element. In the majority of cases this will always be component x inside a `v-for` or something simmilar with a selection action appended to it, the owner of the dom element will always be the component that your rendering and getting as part of the selection.

Comment: Well,I disagree with you for some reasons: 1) the example I gave in the question, if you want to dispatch an event to the "selected" component, I think you can go with a component specialized in handling user selection that send events to the component that owns the selection, that can listen or not to this event. 2) for debugging purpose : ok vue provides already some facility but you may always want better

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense, 1) Your basically agreeing with what I said in the second statement, abstraction would cause this. This approach of finding another less idiomatic way of discerning your applications logic is a guaranteed anti-pattern. 2) Debugging wise your almost always going to fall back to your console, I'm not sure what benefit you would get from being able to find where a DOM component is appended outside of the console environment, brings almost no value.

Comment: Actually, it would be really nice to make it work with a simple "x in a `v-for`", however (except if you can provide me an other way), what you get when you want the user selection (using `document.getSelection().getRangeAt(...)` is a dom node with "almost" nothing else to know what it is (well, you still can tag it to know the component, which is the solution I ended up with).

Comment: This is mostly the crux of the problem I have with your question, if I'm using a framework why am I using things like `document.getSelection().getRangeAt(...)` over simply providing the index to the component and emiting events or passing information to vuex to consume to find what I'm looking for. If you could provide some code I'll provide an answer.

Comment: I can't provide you the code since it is proprietary, but I can give you the idea : it's a component that renders (editable) data trees (using recursive sub-components). Each node of the tree is rendered with a dedicated component. The tree data lives in a vuex store as a flat object (each node has an id which is its key in the object, and parent/children are referenced with this key). Then, there are several actions that can be triggered by outside component (It uses a global event bus in addition to vuex) to perform actions on the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177266/discussion-between-hl037-and-li-x).

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if this is safe or officially supported, but assuming you're trying to access the component from some external-to-Vue code, this will return the VueComponent object for a given DOM element (substitute your own DOM selector as needed):

```
document.getElementById('foo').__vue__
```

If used on the app's root element, it will instead return the Vue constructor object.

(This appears to work in both Vue 1.x and 2.x.)

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly not the most elegant solution, but you can use mixins to achieve this:

```
var elemOwner = {
  mounted: function() {
    this.$el.setAttribute("isVueComponent", this.$options.name);
  }
};
```

As long as you set the mixin to the components you need it in, when you click an element you can test the attributes to see if there's a component name in there.

See this codepen for a fuller example: https://codepen.io/huntleth/pen/EpEWjJ

Clicking the smaller blue square will return the component name of the component that rendered it.

EDIT - It should be noted though that this obviously would only work if the element is actually inside that components root element. I think that would be the case for almost all uses.

Comment: Well...My bad, I actually messed up with the tag, I'm targetting vue.js 2 but I didn't notice there was 2 tags...

Answer (score -1):

Getting `this.$parent` refers to the parent of a component.

Comment: no, that will give you the parent of a *component*. I want the component that rendered a given DOM *element*